# How to update credentials file of aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My credentials file of aws looks this way.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/.aws$ cat credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = *****************
aws_secret_access_key = ***************
[mysubaccount1]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::**********:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
source_profile = default
[mysubaccount2]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::**********:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
source_profile = default
```

Need to see any options to update that here.

I tried below [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) to list the existing profiles to frame any condition, but it is giving error as syntax invalid.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/.aws$ aws configure list-profiles
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

list                                     | get
set                                      | add-model
```

Any aws config commands or any bash script you can suggest to update the details coming from terraform output when we create the account from there to update or add a new profile like mysubaccount3.

Comment: What type of credentials you need to add, API keys, role name, something else? Also, which version of AWS CLI are you using? It seems it's an older version, i.e., version 1.x.x.

Comment: You can just open it with vim and update it.

Answer (score 2):

The command is

```
aws configure list
```

**not**

```
aws configure list-profiles
```

Also, you can easily edit the `.aws/credentials` files with *any* text editor and add/remove/update any entry there.

Comment: require to do in automation, so only cli not with manual steps

Comment: Then write a bash script or use boto3.

Comment: Thanks for giving permission to write a bash script.

Comment: You're most than welcome. Good luck on your automation endeavors!